# Use css to define custom bootstrap column width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I would like define custom classes in css and use them for the components in the HTML instead of giving as below.
`<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">`

I would like to define something like below in css and use it in HTML

```
.fullwidth{
width : "col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12";}
```

HTML:
    `<div class="fullwidth">`

Please help. Also please share any sample links available

Comment: Can you not just use a single class for full width, such as col-lg-12 (this should apply to everything smaller than it also shouldn't it?)

Answer (score 0):

Every box level element (div, p ...) will be stretched 100% of its container. No need for custom classes. If element is inline level element - just add display: block; - to that element and it will be stretched 100% of its container.

Answer (score 0):

Have this script for your `fullwidth`:

```
$("body").on("load", ".fullwidth", function() {
    alert('started');
}
```

Then you will be able to define only `class="fullwidth"`.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an option for you (and I think it should), you could use a css pre-processor like [Sass](http://sass-lang.com) for example. There's good support for it provided by Bootstrap.

If you use that, you can use code like:

```
.fullwidth {
    @include make-xs-column(12);
    @include make-sm-column(12);
    @include make-md-column(12);
    @include make-lg-column(12);
}
```

Although, unless you need to overrule things, there is no need to define everything to 12 columns so you can just set the xs col to 12.

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely looking for a wildcard selector here, I made a 'rainbow' implementation for you which should give you a very solid idea on how to implement it on your own code:

HTML

```
<div class="col-sl-12">Huge</div>
<div class="col-xl-12">Extra large</div>
<div class="col-lg-12">Large</div>
<div class="col-md-12">Medium</div>
<div class="col-sm-12">Small</div>
<div class="col-vs-12">Very Small</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">Extra Small</div>
```

CSS

```
[class$="-12"] { height: 50px; display: block; } /* select attributes that end with '-12' */

/* rainbow colors! */
[class*="sl"] { background-color: purple; } /* select attributes that contain 'sl' */
[class*="xl"] { background-color: blue; }
[class*="lg"] { background-color: green; }
[class*="md"] { background-color: orange; }
[class*="sm"] { background-color: yellow; }
[class*="vs"] { background-color: pink; }
[class*="xs"] { background-color: red; }
```